# Simplifying $\int _1^{\infty }\frac{e^{-\frac{2 t u}{d^2}}}{\sqrt{u}}du$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Can anyone see how to show the following?
$$\int _1^{\infty }\frac{e^{-\frac{2 t u}{d^2}}}{\sqrt{u}}du=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} d \left(1-\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{t}}{d}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{t}}$$

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-exponential-integral.nb)

Motivation: this shows that when $\sqrt{t}/d<1$, exponential integral follows power law, trying to figure out equivalent condition for more general exponential integral:
$$\int _1^{\infty }\frac{ e^{-2 t u d^{-p}}}{u^{1/p}}du\sim O\left(t^{\frac{1}{p}-1}\right)$$

This gives "power-law transition" point for training neural networks like [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.14891)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha = 2t/d^2$ for simplicity.

If we define $x = \sqrt u$ then $u = x^2$ so
$$ \mathcal{I} := 
\int _1^{\infty }\frac{e^{-\alpha u}}{\sqrt{u}}du=
\int_1^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2} \frac{1}{x} 2x \; dx
=
2 \int_1^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}  \; dx
$$
Then $z = \sqrt \alpha x$ gives
$$
\mathcal I
= \frac{2}{\sqrt \alpha} \int_{\sqrt \alpha}^\infty e^{-z^2}\, dz
$$
which can be expressed easily in terms of [the complementary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Complementary_error_function) and hence the error function.

The cleanup from there and the algebra for your particular $\alpha$ I'll leave to you.